# Change the value of variable on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have to select a marker in a map based on the button click. I have multiple marker with each marker associated to button below. I want to change "myloc" on that button click and by default it must select 13, 100.

### Html

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value = "First">
    <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value = "Second">
</div>
```

### JS

```
let myloc = new L.LatLng(13, 100);
var map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 12);

$(function () {
    $('.btn-a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var clsName = $(this).val();
        var lat, long;

        if (clsName == 'First') {
            lat = 13;
            long = 100;
        } else if(clasName = 'Second') {
            lat = 14;
            long = 101;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Constants by definition can't have their values changed. Use `let` instead.

Comment: @Utkanos yes i had let in my code. I wrote const here. Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see you setting the myLoc object anywhere. You are just assigning value for lat, lng. Check the snippet below to see if it answers your question.

Here, you initiliaze `myLoc` and on button click get new values for `lat, lng` and set it at the end again for `myLoc`

```js
//just a temp function to show the example. Dont add this in your code
var L = {
  LatLng: function(lat, lng) {
    console.log("Current Values for Lat, Lng: " + lat + " , "+ lng);
  }
}


let myloc = new L.LatLng(13, 100);
//var map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 12);

$(function () {
    $('.btn-a').on('click', function(e){
      //  e.preventDefault();
        var clsName = $(this).val();
        var lat, long;

        if (clsName == 'First') {
            lat = 13;
            long = 100;
         } else if(clasName = 'Second') {
            lat = 14;
            long = 101;
        }
        
        //set the myloc here
         myloc = new L.LatLng(lat, long);
         //then map again
          //L.map('map').setView(myloc, 12)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value = "First">
    <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value = "Second">
</div>
```

Comment: I just add question till here. After assigning there are code related to map and other functions where this lat and long is being used

Comment: You want to assign the lat long to myloc right? Or is your question something else

Comment: @TheUkown yes i want to assign the lat long to myloc.

Comment: Ok so that’s what the code which I posted does.. see the last of the lines where after the click you set a lat long and then assign it to myLoc after the if-else loop. Run the snippet to see.

Comment: It calls the exact same function L.LatLng as in your code

Answer (score 1):

Below is an approach you can use, similar to what you we're doing. The example uses event delegation to monitor button clicks and then sets the `lat` and `long` variables accordingly. Those variables are then used to update the value of the global `myLoc`. I used an object literal in place of your `new L.LatLng` object for simplicity.

```js
let myLoc = {
  lat: 13,
  long: 100
};
//new L.LatLng(13, 100);

document.querySelector('.row').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.type === 'button') {
    let lat = 0;
    let long = 0;
    if (e.target.id === 'btn-first') {
      lat = 13;
      long = 100;
    } else if (e.target.id === 'btn-second') {
      lat = 14;
      long = 101;
    }

    myLoc = {
      lat,
      long
    };

    console.log(`myLoc.lat: ${myLoc.lat}; myLoc.long ${myLoc.long}`);
    //new L.LatLng(lat, long);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value="First">
  <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value="Second">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
            $('.btn-a').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var $this = $(this).val();
                    if ($this == 'First') {
                        $(this).val('One');
                    } else if ($this == 'Second') {
                        $(this).val('Two');
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```